# Can xeCJK be used with the font Times?

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

The following minimal example fed into `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
    Test 汉语
\end{document}
```

typesets the CJK correctly, but does not typeset the Roman text in Times, but in Computer Modern instead.

What's the correct way to have xeCJK only affect the CJK text and leave any Roman font settings unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the XeLaTeX methods. For instance this works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Kai} % I don't have your MingLiu font
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} % choose any Times-like font

\begin{document}
    Test 汉语
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand this correctly, there's no way I can use the in-built Times (with small caps) -- it's all in or all out?

Comment: @jogloran If the system font has no small caps, you're out of luck. TeX Gyre Termes *has* small caps.

Comment: A free Times-alike with small caps! Thanks. I ended up submitting my paper with caps instead of small caps, but I'll keep this in mind for future work.